# Admin Access in Amazon AppStream image instances for registry edits?

Tags: amazon-web-services, registry, edit, aws-appstream

I am trying to write a script in Amazon AppStream that will edit the registry's, and ultimately register a user to Tableau and activate a license for them. The script on my desktop runs perfectly, and does exactly what it needs to do, which is edit the registry, register it with Tableau, and activate the license.

Below is the line of code intended to edit the registry:

```
"C:\Scripts\User_Tab.reg"
```

I have successfully created an image of the script in AppStream, the first thing it does is try and edit the registry, but get's blocked because "editing has been disabled by your administrator." **Is there anyway to enable this so that my script can run?**

["editing has been disabled by your administrator " - error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOlTu.png)

As a side note, my script is also not behaving as expected in other ways. Even though it will run Tableau, it seems unable to perform any Tableau specific commands, such as activating the license. Which is weird, because they all have the same file path, and it works on my desktop...

Any help appreciated.

**EDIT**

A similar issue happens when I try to run a PowerShell script to edit the registries, based on information I obtained from [this question](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=260852).

Running a PowerShell script also requires a degree of administrator access that I don't know how to give an image instance.

[PowerShell Script requires admin password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKRt6.png)

*This question appears to be more about giving admin access to a image instance in AppStream than it does about registries. The title has been changed from "Editing Registry's in Amazon AppStream image instances?" to "Admin Access in Amazon AppStream image instances for registry edits?" to reflect this.*

Comment: A `.reg` file requires to be run `as Administrator`, as do most alternatives when non `Current_User` keys are being written to.

Comment: Do you know how I can set administrator access in an AppStream image instance? The .reg file registers fine in the Image Builder on admin, but after the image is created of the script I have no idea of how to give it access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[A solution to this has been given here by awsMuraliR](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=293885&tstart=0)

Where in order to get around this error you need to instead write a PowerShell script to edit the registry, essentially avoiding the admin access requested for editing the registry using a .bat file.

Then, the get around admin access required for running a PowerShell script, you need a .bat file to run the PowerShell script for you.

Create an image of the .bat file that runs the PowerShell script.